# Fullcalendar Events JSON not populating agenda{Day,Week}

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

the title really says it all. I'm trying to populate a [fullcalendar widget](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) through [JSON](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/). The generated JSON looks as follows, and it seems to be compliant to [what fullcalendar expects](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Here's an example of the generated JSON:

```
[
  {
    "color": "#FFDB58",
    "start": "2012-03-05 10:00:00",
    "end": "2012-03-05 10:30:00",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "event 1"
  },
  {
    "color": "#6495ED",
    "start": "2012-03-05 10:00:00",
    "end": "2012-03-05 13:30:00",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "event 2"
  }
]
```

(it is really output as one single line, I intended it here just for clarity).

The problem is: I can see the two events in the "month view", and in the basicWeek and basicDay view. But in my web application I want to use the agendaWeek and agendaDay views, and those are empty.

How can I debug what is happening?

Thanks,

David

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm not sure your problem is with your JSON. Can you post the rest of your calendar declaration?

Comment: what version of the calendar are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation, it turned out that the JSON was missing `allDay: False` (or `True`) -- even if the docs say it's optional, it seems like the agenda* views need it.

Answer (score 0):

David, what are your settings for FullCalendar? Are you using allDay:false? Which browser? Have you tried other browsers? I'm not sure if it's related but using the datetime format you have I had issues displaying event in all views on IE but the same files worked fine in Chrome. I changed my datetime format to 2012-03-05T10:00:00 and it worked in both. I'm using a json feed.